# Why isn't there any "official" PHP Formula for Homebrew

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

Homebrew seems to be a really powerful package manager for osx, and the amount of available formulas is really convenient, but I can't understand something : Why isn't there any PHP formula for homebrew ?

I mean, there are "custom formulas" to add to homebrew, but no official one. 
The weird part is there are a lot of PHP extension available in hombrew, out of the box, such as apc, imagick, xdebug, ffmpeg-php but no PHP. I can't understand. Could someone explain ? Is there a reason ? A licence issue, maybe ?

Comment: I presume you know PHP comes pre-installed on Mac OS X.

Comment: Questions about using or configuring software belong on ServerFault or SuperUser if not server administration related. This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I suspect a very real reason (as per my comment) is that Mac OS X has PHP pre-installed (fire up a terminal and type "`php --version`") and hence there's no need to provide the base PHP package.

Additionally, according to the [Homebrew github page](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki):

> Remember! We don’t accept formula into
>   mxcl/master that dupes stuff already
>   included with OS X.

This is explained in additional detail on the [Formula Cookbook page](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Formula-Cookbook).

Comment: The reason that other packaging systems have supplied their own PHP builds is that the Apple built-in one has historically been awful, and very difficult to build extensions for (requiring quad-format binaries - PPC/intel, 32/64), plus it was missing dev libs and was built with shared lib support disabled. I'm not sure if that's changed in Lion.

Answer (score 11):

See also: https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php

> This repository contains PHP-related formulae for [Homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew).
>
> (This replaces the PHP formulae that used to live under [adamv's homebrew-alt repository](https://github.com/adamv/homebrew-alt).)
>
> The purpose of this repository is to allow PHP developers to quickly retrieve working, up-to-date formulae. The mainline Homebrew repositories are maintained by non-php developers, so testing/maintaining PHP-related brews has fallen by the wayside...

Comment: [homebrew-alt](https://github.com/adamv/homebrew-alt) will soon be removing php, so it is preferred to use [homebrew-php](https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php) going forward

Answer (score -2):

Also, you can install [hombrew-alt](https://github.com/adamv/homebrew-alt) (Alternate formulae repos for Homebrew), it has a php formula that's works great.

Comment: That homebrew-alt link is dead